# How to add line in xml file

Tags: linux, xml

I want to add one line in xml file.
My xml file contains as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration>     
  <ftp_destination_ip>0.0.0.0</ftp_destination_ip>
  <ftp_destination_user>root</ftp_destination_user>
  <ftp_destination_pass>undefined</ftp_destination_pass>        
  <other_unix_backup_path>/root/BACKUP</other_unix_backup_path>
  <other_backup_folder>BACKUP</other_backup_folder>
  <source_confirmation_needed>false</source_confirmation_needed>
  <keep_ems_running_after_restore>false</keep_ems_running_after_restore>
  <remote_connection_timeout>120000</remote_connection_timeout >
    <history>
        <manage_backup_history>true</manage_backup_history>
        <backup_history_num_of_days>7</backup_history_num_of_days>
    </history>
</configuration>
```

And I want to add two lines that will be 3th and 4th line in the XML:

```
  <remote_connection_protocol>sftp</remote_connection_protocol>
  <ftp_destination_ip>0.0.0.0</ftp_destination_ip>
```

The output should be like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration>     
  <!--remote connection protocol>false|ftp|sftp</remote connection protocol-->
  <remote_connection_protocol>sftp</remote_connection_protocol>
  <ftp_destination_ip>0.0.0.0</ftp_destination_ip>
  <ftp_destination_user>root</ftp_destination_user>
  <ftp_destination_pass>undefined</ftp_destination_pass>        
  <other_unix_backup_path>/root/BACKUP</other_unix_backup_path>
  <other_backup_folder>BACKUP</other_backup_folder>
  <source_confirmation_needed>false</source_confirmation_needed>
  <keep_ems_running_after_restore>false</keep_ems_running_after_restore>
  <remote_connection_timeout>120000</remote_connection_timeout >
    <history>
        <manage_backup_history>true</manage_backup_history>
        <backup_history_num_of_days>7</backup_history_num_of_days>
    </history>
</configuration>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I edited

Comment: It should be 3th and 4th line. My mistake. fixed.

Comment: but literally its 4th and 5th line

Comment: while `sed`, `awk` and friends could do the job, you might whish to use `xmlstartlet` to do such thing, see p16 **Include one XML document into another using XInclude** http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
sed '4i\  <remote_connection_protocol>sftp</remote_connection_protocol>\n  <ftp_destination_ip>0.0.0.0</ftp_destination_ip>' file.xml
```

- `4i` to add the content at the 4th line of the file.
- `\n` for a newline.

if it works, add `-i` option for inline edit.

Comment: My mistake. It works! Thanks a lot!